# name the dict in a list and send as response

Tags: python, django

My frontend receives as a REST call response currently as:

```
[
    {
        "Total": 54063120.8235,
        "Percentage": 126.1001
    },
    {
        "Total": 1464405,
        "Percentage": 0
    }
]
```

but I want:

```
[
    Income:{
        "Total": 54063120.8235,
        "Percentage": 126.1001
    },
    taxes:{
        "Total": 1464405,
        "Percentage": 0
    }
]
```

What change shall I do?

I am saving my list as

```
result = [Income, taxes]
```

Comment: What you want is not a valid Python data structure.

Comment: We can modify your result to desired result. But probably there is a way to directly get to desired result which we can help you only if you give more details.

Comment: I want to send this type of response to my frontend which is in React.. Is it possible anyhow?

Comment: Turn it into a Dict of Dicts, instead of List of dicts: `result = {"Income": Income, "taxes": taxes}`

Comment: @IvanStarostin turning into dict of dicts is always an option, I thought of that first, but I just wanted to know if this is possible?

Comment: `Income` and `taxes` must be str in python,  in javascript, the interpret treat this key as string automaticly. so just add quotes and  all it is done. recommend you better read the [json package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to understard the conversion.